# Adding 1 values together from different rows where value in column matches

Tags: python, pandas

I currently have 2 datasets.
The first contains a list of football teams with values I have worked out. 
[image]

I have a second dataset has a list of teams that are playing today

[image]

What I would like to do is add to dataset2 the mean number of both teams that are playing each other so the outcome would be

[image]

I have looked through Stack Overflow and not found anything that been able to help. I am fairly new to working with Pandas so I am not sure if this is possible or not.

As an example data set:

```
data1 = {
         'DATAMECI': ['17/06/2020', '17/06/2020'],
         'ORAMECI': ['11:30', '15:30'],
         'TXTECHIPA1': ['Everton', 'Man City'],
    'TXTECHIPA2': ['Hull', 'Leeds'],
    }
data2 = {
         'Team': ['Hull', 'Leeds','Everton', 'Man City'],
         'Home0-0': ['80', '78','80', '66'],
         'Home1-0': ['81', '100','90', '70'],
    'Away0-1': ['88', '42','75', '69'],
    }
```

with the desired output being

```
Desired = {
    'DATAMECI': ['17/06/2020', '17/06/2020'],
         'ORAMECI': ['11:30', '15:30'],
         'TXTECHIPA1': ['Everton', 'Man City'],
    'TXTECHIPA2': ['Hull', 'Leeds'],
             'Home0-0': ['80', '72'],
         'Home1-0': ['86', '85'],
    'Away0-1': ['86', '56',],
    }
```

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of the data, instead share a sample data set that we can copy from and work on it. Screenshots will not attract people to answer your question as it takes time to create the sample data set to work on. Also, the two data frames do not have common teams, can you be more specific in your sample data?

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I have added sample data including an example of the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option as opposed to iterating over rows, is you can merge the datasets, then iterate over the columns.

I also noticed your desired output is rounded, so I have that there as well

**Sample:**

```
data1 = pd.DataFrame({
         'DATAMECI': ['17/06/2020', '17/06/2020'],
         'ORAMECI': ['11:30', '15:30'],
         'TXTECHIPA1': ['Everton', 'Man City'],
    'TXTECHIPA2': ['Hull', 'Leeds'],
    })
data2 = pd.DataFrame({
         'Team': ['Hull', 'Leeds','Everton', 'Man City'],
         'Home0-0': ['80', '78','80', '66'],
         'Home1-0': ['81', '100','90', '70'],
    'Away0-1': ['88', '42','75', '69'],
    })





Desired = pd.DataFrame({
    'DATAMECI': ['17/06/2020', '17/06/2020'],
         'ORAMECI': ['11:30', '15:30'],
         'TXTECHIPA1': ['Everton', 'Man City'],
    'TXTECHIPA2': ['Hull', 'Leeds'],
             'Home0-0': ['80', '72'],
         'Home1-0': ['86', '85'],
    'Away0-1': ['86', '56',],
    })
```

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd

cols = [ x for x in data2 if 'Home' in x or 'Away' in x ]
data1 = data1.merge(data2.rename(columns={'Team':'TXTECHIPA1'}), how='left', on=['TXTECHIPA1'])
data1 = data1.merge(data2.rename(columns={'Team':'TXTECHIPA2'}), how='left', on=['TXTECHIPA2'])

for col in cols:
    data1[col] = data1[[col + '_x', col + '_y']].astype(int).mean(axis=1).round(0)
    data1 = data1.drop([col + '_x', col + '_y'], axis=1)
```

**Output:**

```
print(data1)
     DATAMECI ORAMECI TXTECHIPA1 TXTECHIPA2  Home0-0  Home1-0  Away0-1
0  17/06/2020   11:30    Everton       Hull     80.0     86.0     82.0
1  17/06/2020   15:30   Man City      Leeds     72.0     85.0     56.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for adding the data. Here is a simple way using loops. Loop through the `df2` (upcoming matches). Find the equivalent rows of the participating teams from `df1` (team statistics). Now you will have 2 rows from `df1`. Average the desired columns and add it to `df2`. 
Considering similar structure as your data set, here is an example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'team': ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'],
                    'home0-0': [86, 78, 65, 67, 100],
                    'home1-0': [76, 86, 67, 100, 0],
                    'home0-1': [91, 88, 75, 100, 67],
                    'home1-1': [75, 67, 67, 100, 100],
                    'away0-0': [57, 86, 71, 91, 50],
                    'away1-0': [73, 50, 71, 100, 100],
                    'away0-1': [78, 62, 40, 80, 0],
                    'away1-1': [50, 71, 33, 100, 0]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2020-06-17', '2020-06-17', '2020-06-17', '2020-06-17', '2020-06-17', '2020-06-17', '2020-06-17'],
                    'time': [1800, 1200, 1100, 2005, 1000, 1800, 1800],
                    'team1': ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'one', 'three'],
                    'team2': ['five', 'four', 'two', 'one', 'three', 'two', 'four']})

for i, row in df2.iterrows():
    team1 = df1[df1['team']==row['team1']]
    team2 = df1[df1['team']==row['team2']]
    for col in df1.columns[1:]:
        df2.loc[i, col]=(np.mean([team1[col].values[0], team2[col].values[0]]))

print(df2)
```

For your sample data set:

```
for i, row in data1.iterrows():
    team1 = data2[data2['Team']==row['TXTECHIPA1']]
    team2 = data2[data2['Team']==row['TXTECHIPA2']]
    for col in data2.columns[1:]:
        data1.loc[i, col]=(np.mean([int(team1[col].values[0]), int(team2[col].values[0])]))

print(data1)
```

Result:

```
     DATAMECI ORAMECI TXTECHIPA1 TXTECHIPA2  Home0-0  Home1-0  Away0-1
0  17/06/2020   11:30    Everton       Hull     80.0     85.5     81.5
1  17/06/2020   15:30   Man City      Leeds     72.0     85.0     55.5
```